# Summing the values of several R Lists based on a date key

Tags: r, list

I am working on a script where I have two lists and I am trying to combine the results so I get a new list. Each list has a date and then two numbers. The lists look like this:

```
         date clicks impressions
1  2019-06-01      1           2 
2  2019-06-02      0           0 
3  2019-06-03      100         120
```

and

```
        date clicks impressions
1  2019-06-01      2          14
2  2019-06-02      3          14
3  2019-06-03     11          29
```

I'd like a single list that is

```
        date clicks impressions
1  2019-06-01      3          16
2  2019-06-02      3          14
3  2019-06-03     111         149
```

What is the best way to accomplish this. In time I will have 20 - 30 more lists that will be added to this, so I'll want to pull the first list and then combine with the second and then a third and so on. I don't know if I'll be able to assume that each date will be in each list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your list is called `list_df`, you can bind them all together using `bind_rows`, `group_by` `date` and then `sum` all the other columns.

```
library(dplyr)

list_df %>%
   bind_rows() %>%
   group_by(date) %>%
   summarise_all(sum)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  date       clicks impressions
#  <fct>       <int>       <int>
#1 2019-06-01      3          16
#2 2019-06-02      3          14
#3 2019-06-03    111         149
```

which in base R could be achieved using `Reduce`

```
aggregate(.~date, Reduce(rbind, list_df), sum)
```

Comment: I like where this is going! Thank you for jumping in. My data are in two lists right now, so I'm looking to combine them. So, I would have a list1 and list2 and looking to combine into list_df in this example. How would I do that?

Comment: @JAB Assuming what you have is dataframe and not list, you could do `list_df <- list(list1, list2)` for only two of them. More generally, you can do `list_df <- mget(ls(pattern = "list\\d+"))` which can be done for multiple dataframes together.

Comment: OK. Cool! That's awesome. I'll give a shot, too!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list_df)[, lapply(.SD, sum), date]
#         date clicks impressions
#1: 2019-06-01      3          16
#2: 2019-06-02      3          14
#3: 2019-06-03    111         149
```

#### data

```
list_df <- mget(paste0("df", 1:2))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do:

```
cbind(date=df1[,1],do.call(`+`, list(df1[,-1],df2[,-1])),
            row.names = NULL)
        date clicks impressions
1 2019-06-01      3          16
2 2019-06-02      3          14
3 2019-06-03    111         149
```

If you are not sure about the presence of dates(can then `cbind` as above):

```
do.call(`+`,lapply(list(df1,df2), function(x) x[,-1]))
  clicks impressions
1      3          16
2      3          14
3    111         149
```

This assumes that the data sets will have the same structure always.